# Why is the value of d 1 and not 6?

Tags: c, equality

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int a = 10, b = 5, c = 5;
        int d;
        d = b + c==a;
        printf("%d", d);
    }
```

I thought `c==a` will evaluate to `1` and `b+1` i.e `5+1=6` will be the output but it is `1`, if I change `+` to `*` then output is `0`. Why?

Comment: See operator precedence. It is `(b+c) == a`.

Comment: And then, c isn't even equal to a!

Comment: @ rafix07 ,yes got it.thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is a case of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). `+` has higher precedence than `==`, so this

```
b + c==a;
```

is the same as

```
(b + c) == a;
```

So it turns into

```
10 == 10;
```

Which is `1`.

---

> if I change + to * then output is 0

Then we have `(5 * 5) == 10` which is `25 == 10` which is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

See the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

`+` has a higher precedence than `==` and `==` has higher precedence than `=`

So the equation becomes

```
d = ((b + c)==a)
d = ((5 + 5)==10);
d = (10==10)
d = 1;
```

If you have

```
d = b * c==a;
d = ((b*c)==a);
d = ((5*5)==10);
d = (25==10);
d = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must attend to operator precedence whenever you use more than one operator in a statement. The precedence of '+' is higher than '==', thus

```
b + c==a;
```

is interpreted as:

```
(b + c) == a;
```

If this isn't what you want, then you should enclose 'c==a' with parentheses:

```
b + (c == a) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the statement c==a in paranthases

d = b + (c==a);